# Modifying app.config on fly

Tags: .net, winforms, .net-4.0

Seems a trivial question, but surprisingly, found only some solutions like [this one](http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/articles/64871.aspx), which explain how to add some properties, using deprecated functions. I'd rather want to edit one. So,  how it's done in .NET 4.0?

To be more specific, need to set the location of database, in `<connectionStrings>` property.

Comment: You can't write to the .config file, UAC stops you.  It is meant to be edited directly by an admin that runs an editor from an elevated command prompt.  An application scope setting stops being helpful when you want to edit yourself.  Just make it a user scope setting (awkward for a connection string) or spin your own with a .xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is adapted from [this blog post](http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/articles/64871.aspx) and tested on .NET 4:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;

class Program
{
    static void ShowConfig()
    {
        // For read access you do not need to call the OpenExeConfiguraton
        foreach (ConnectionStringSettings item in ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", item.Name, item.ConnectionString);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ShowConfig();

        var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

        var conSettings = new ConnectionStringSettings("NewName", "New connstring value");
        config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Add(conSettings);
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");

        Console.WriteLine("===UPDATE===");
        ShowConfig();

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="db1" connectionString="blah"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

On my PC it prints

```
Key: LocalSqlServer, Value: data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true
Key: db1, Value: blah
===UPDATE===
Key: LocalSqlServer, Value: data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true
Key: db1, Value: blah
Key: NewName, Value: New connstring value
```

Comment: Could you also post the "using" directives? Can't get  ConfigurationManager in my app

Comment: @Nordvind done. You will need to add a reference to `System.Configuration.dll`